# Customize ribbon permanently

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a bunch of macros to make repetitive tasks in the office less time-consuming.
I'm constantly editing them, adding functionality and tweaking.
Each time, I then have to go around to each employee in the office, unhide their PERSONAL.xlsb file, remove the old module, add the new and updated module.

These macros are controlled from a custom tab on the ribbon, with 15 or so buttons, each triggering a macro. 
Every now and then, I have to add/remove/change buttons on the custom tab, which then has to be done for everyone in the office individually.

I was looking into scripting the buttons onto the ribbon, but that doesn't seem possible from what I've read.
I ended up making a customui xlsm file, from a tutorial I saw on this site, but this is no good, because the Custom Tab disappears if the xlsm workbook is hidden, or not open.

Basically, I want to be able to go to a computer, copy across PERSONAL.xlsb and CUSTOMRIBBON.xlsm into the XLSTART folder, and have it all ready to go straight away.

Is there a way? or is it just not possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: credit for this answer goes to Ron de Bruin.

---

You don't really need to separate files. All you need is one file that stores the ribbon and the code. Follow the below to see how this works...

---

Follow [Ron de Bruin's tutorial](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) on adding controls to Ribbon using [Custom UI Editors for Microsoft Office](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip).

It's as simple as

- Create a workbook and save it as Add-in `CustomRibbon.xlam` and put that file in the `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\`
- download [Custom UI Editors for Microsoft Office](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip). When you open it you want to load the `CustomRibbon.xlam` and right click it and select `Office 2010 Custom UI`

[image]

- On the right hand side of the window paste the below XML

  ```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
      <tabs>
        <tab idMso="TabHome" >
          <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">
            <button id="customButton1" label="Click Me" size="large" onAction="Macro1" imageMso="HappyFace" />
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabs>
    </ribbon>
  </customUI>
  ```
- Save changes and close the program.
- Open Excel and you should see the new icon on your ribbon

[image]

- You can assign a macro to the button in your `CustomRibbon.xlam` but you would have to directly open the `CustomRibbon.xlam` and open VBE and insert a module. Then in the module stick the following

`Sub Macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
        MsgBox "Hi There"
     End Sub`

- again, save and close. Note that in the XML you have assigned a value to the `OnAction` property to `Macro1`. Obviously with more buttons and more macros this where you assign the trigger for each button.
- Turn on developer tab, click on Add-ins and make sure your `CustomRibbon` is turned on
- Now open Excel (not CustomRibbon ) and when you click the *smiley face* button on the ribbon the code in `Macro1` should execute showing a Message Box

So as you can see, if you put all your business logic and the ribbon's XML in the `CustomRibbon.xlam` and save it as an add-in on each machine then when you update the original `CustomRibbon` all you have to do on each client is just overwrite the `CustomRibbon` file with a new one.

I hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: Yes perfect, thanks, i had already come across the other tutorial, so i have already produced the .xlsm file with the new tab and buttons programmed into it with customui editor. jsut didnt know all i had to do was drop the file into the addins folder. thanks again

Comment: i tried it, didn't work. my xlsm file works, i open it, theres the tab. but i put it in the addins folder, doesnt show up

Comment: when i put customribbon.xlsm into the xlstart folder, it opens with xl, but as soon as i swap workbook - the tabs are gone. if there was a way to fix them to excel once they appear....

Comment: @user3709812 it's not an `xlsm` it should be an `xlam`

Comment: oh ok, i thought that was just a type, with s and a being next to eachother on the keyboard. I will try again with the xlam. :D thanks

Comment: @user3709812 no that's not a typo - they are different formats, try `Save As` and save it as a `Excel Add-in` which is `*.xlam` format

Comment: ok i dropped the xlam file into xlstart and its all good, didnt work in the add-ins folder, all sweet in the xlstart folder :D   >>>>>>>>>>>>>   thanks to everyone for their help <<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: the new ribbon didnt show, when i used xlam but inside the add-ins folder, now that i moved it to the xlstart folder, everything works perfect.   .xlam + xlstart = win

Comment: It's not supposed to be in the `XLSTART` folder. It's supposed be in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns` and you should open `Developer` tab, click `Add-ins` and turn on the `CustomRibbon` - by ticking it. Please re-read the answer carefully

Comment: Yeah sorry, Im up to speed now.  Thanks to everyone for their help.  Have learnt alot from you all already.  I ended up keeping the personal.xlsb and customribbon.xlam files separate and just use a batch file delete old files and copy new ones into xlstart folder for updating in the future.  But its nice to know it can all go into one file.  The reason my xlam file wasnt working before is because i didnt put the (control as iribboncontrol) in my macros, so they were not being triggered. all good now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having issues with this:

As stated above the CustomRibbon.xlam file should be saved/located in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\`

I suspect anyone not having luck with this was missing some of the required fields of XML as per this site on [CustomUI](http://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html):

**Reading the Custom UI Code**

In the xml code, you can see that there is a heading for each part of the custom UI:

- Namespace
- Ribbon
- Tabs
- Group
- Button

Each item has a unique ID, a label, and perhaps other properties, such as an icon and a macro that runs when the button is clicked.

[For example, here is the code for one of the buttons in the Contoso Tools group. Line breaks were added, to make the code easier to read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnjJ2.jpg)

Excel Ribbon Custom button code

- The ID -- customButton1 -- is unique. Each ID can only used once in
  the code.
- The label -- ConBold -- is the text that will appear on the button in
  the Ribbon tab.
- The image -- Bold -- will also appear on the button
- The size is set to Large, so it will be easy to see on the Ribbon.
- The onAction -- conBoldSub -- is the name of the macro that will run
  when the button is clicked.

it was causing issues since some of the required fields (customUI, ribbon, tabs..) of the code was cut off in the posted answer above, the whole complete code that works is:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabHome" >
                    <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">
                    <button id="customButton1" label="Click Me" size="large" onAction="Macro1" imageMso="HappyFace" />
                    </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Once all the required XML fields are present it should work as expected. 
At this point follow the original answers instructions and it should work without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

They have recently updated **custom UI editor** software to support all version of MS office as earlier version was not properly supporting for upper versions (Office 2010+ )

Now the software is renamed as **OFFICE RIBBONX EDITOR** and its available for download

Here is the links for more information and Download:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/latest

Big thanks to 'Ron de Bruin', 'Fernando Andreu' and 'Trang Luu'